# How to get all keys in ResourceManager

Tags: asp.net-core

Recently I've created a new ASP.NET Core Web Application and one of my requirements is to expose an endpoint for clients to get all the translation keys and values stored in .resx files.

Before ASP.NET Core I was able to do something like this. But the command `ResourceManager.GetResourceSet()` is not recognized anymore:

```
public IActionResult Get(string lang)
{
    var resourceObject = new JObject();

    var resourceSet = Resources.Strings.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(new CultureInfo(lang), true, true);
    IDictionaryEnumerator enumerator = resourceSet.GetEnumerator();
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        resourceObject.Add(enumerator.Key.ToString(), enumerator.Value.ToString());
    }

    return Ok(resourceObject);
}
```

Are there any new ways to get all keys and values of a resource in ASP.NET Core Project?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you will look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization), you will see that ASP.NET Core Team has introduced `IStringLocalizer` and `IStringLocalizer<T>`. Under the cover, `IStringLocalizer` use `ResourceManager` and `ResourceReader`. Basic usage from the documentation:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Localization;

namespace Localization.StarterWeb.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class AboutController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IStringLocalizer<AboutController> _localizer;

        public AboutController(IStringLocalizer<AboutController> localizer)
        {
            _localizer = localizer;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public string Get()
        {
            return _localizer["About Title"];
        }
    }
}
```

For getting all keys you can do that:

```
var resourceSet = _localizer.GetAllStrings().Select(x => x.Name);
```

But for getting all keys by language, you need to use `WithCulture` method:

```
var resourceSet = _localizer.WithCulture(new CultureInfo(lang))
                            .GetAllStrings().Select(x => x.Name);
```

So when you inject `IStringLocalizer` into your controller it will be instantiated as an instance of [ResourceManagerStringLocalizer](https://github.com/aspnet/Localization/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Localization/ResourceManagerStringLocalizer.cs) class with default `CultureInfo` for your application, and for getting resources specific for your `lang` variable, you need to use `WithCulture` method, because it creates new `ResourceManagerStringLocalizer` class for a specific `CultureInfo`.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Very much appreciated.